# How to import electron in angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, requirejs, electron

I am trying to import [electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron) for printing the invoice from my app
 using

```
import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
```

But it is throwing the error.

> fs.existsSync is not a function

Also, I have tried to require it from the index.html page like

```
<script>  
        var electron = require('electron');  
</script>
```

but getting

> require is not defined

Comment: Wrong way around. You use "angular" **inside** electron, which is an environment that allows "browser like code" to run within it. Rather than using "it" in the "browser".

Comment: I want to print the invoice from my app so I have imported BrowserWindow

Comment: please try this. it may works. 
$ npm install electron --save-dev

**const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')**

Comment: @MdAlamin I have tried but geeting `Cannot find name 'require'.` error

Comment: @sam what is your **angular cli** version??

Comment: @MdAlamin Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10

Comment: you can try it,
Step 1:  **npm install --save @types/node**
Step 2:  edit your src/tsconfig.app.json file and add the following in place of the empty "types": [],
**"types": [ "node" ],"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]** please let me khow its works or not.

Comment: Don't think it's necessary to install types to use require. Just declare the require anywhere in your typescript file. Like so:

declare var require: any;

and then use it to invoke whatever you want.

Comment: @MdAlamin now `fs.existsSync is not a function` error

Comment: @sam  Run the command **npm install --save electron @types/electron**  Then import it again **import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron'**

Comment: @MdAlamin getting same `fs.existsSync is not a function` error

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far is to use [ngx-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-electron)

In your electron simply do:

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('ping', (event, arg) => {
    console.log('RECEIVED PING FROM ANGULAR APP', event, arg);
    event.sender.sendSync('pong', 'yeah yeah yeah');
});
```

In your angular app:

```
import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        NgxElectronModule
    ],
    ...
})
```

And inside your component:

```
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';
...
constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService)
...
if (this._electronService.isElectronApp) {
            this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on('pong', (event, arg) => {
                console.log(
                    'RECEIVED RESPONSE FROM ELECTRON TO ANGULAR APP',
                    event,
                    arg
                );
            });
        }
...
this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send(
            'ping',
            'wow wow wow'
        );
```